# Changing layer symbology in QGIS 3 with QgsFeatureRendererV2

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, symbology, vector

I am updating a QGIS Plugin from QGIS 2 to 3 and I am struggling with changing the layer symbology (a single symbol type for a line layer). I would like to have all lines in my layer to have the same color and the same thickness.
For QGIS 2 it worked like this:

```py
symbols = iface.activeLayer().rendererV2().symbols()
symbol = symbols[0]
symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(0, 225, 0))
symbol.setWidth(0.75)
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(iface.activeLayer())
```

For QGIS 3, I understood from the [API break documentation](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html) that `rendererV2()` has been renamed to `renderer()`. Further, `symbols()` has been removed:

> *symbols( QgsRenderContext& context ) method should be used instead (previously available as symbols2 in PyQGIS bindings).*

I find it hard to connect this information and what I find under the [QgsRenderContext documentation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRenderContext.html) to my problem.

An explanation on how to solve such issue based on the documentations would be helpful.

Comment: The correct answer depends on your renderer type - is this single symbol, categorized, or something else?

Comment: @ndawson: a single symbol type for a line layer. I would like to have all lines in my layer to have the same color and the same thickness. I will add this info to the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it's a single symbol renderer, then something like:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
single_symbol_renderer = layer.renderer()

symbol = single_symbol_renderer.symbol()
symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(0, 225, 0))
symbol.setWidth(0.75)

# more efficient than refreshing the whole canvas, which requires a redraw of ALL layers
layer.triggerRepaint()

# update legend for layer
qgis.utils.iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

Comment: Further, a short explanation on how to solve such issue based on the documentations would be helpful. E.g. starting with the QgsVectorLayer, I see that from the [classQgsVectorLayer](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html) I can retrieve with `renderer()` an object of the [classQgsFeatureRenderer](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRenderer.html). However, there I see no function `symbol()` to retrieve a [classQgsMarkerSymbol](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMarkerSymbol.html), which I need to then use `setColor()` etc.

Comment: You need to also check the subclasses - in this case calling renderer() on the layer will give you the subclass, a QgsSingleSymbolRenderer. Checking https://qgis.org/api/classQgsSingleSymbolRenderer.html shows the symbol/setSymbol methods.