# Getting and setting the symbol sizes for a graduated layer in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, symbology, qgis-3, classification

I have a whole set of maps that have graduated colors based on a set ramp and I also like to change the symbol sizes as it makes anomalous areas stand out even more.
Id like to change the symbol sizes with the console (if I use the automatic classification by value the symbol sizes are reset).

In QGIS 2.18 I could do it by:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
symbols = layer.rendererV2().symbols()
symbols[0].setSize(1.5)
symbols[1].setSize(1.75)
symbols[2].setSize(2)
symbols[3].setSize(2.25)
symbols[4].setSize(2.5)
symbols[5].setSize(2.75)
```

In QGIS 3 the `rendererV2` has been renamed (to renderer), but I am stuck on how to call the symbols. I know its likely a python 3 syntax I am missing, but it hangs on

```
symbols = layer.rendererV2().symbols()

TypeError: symbols(self, context: QgsRenderContext): not enough arguments
```

I did manage to get at the symbols a different way:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
renderer = layer.renderer()
renderer.ranges()[1].symbol().size()
ranges = renderer.ranges()
ranges[0].symbol().size()
```

but if I do:

```
ranges[0].symbol().setSize(1.5)
```

it does not actually change anything and a layer refresh does not help. If I query the size again it tells me the original size, and I guess it is the default value the graduated renderer is using.

In the change log for v3, `QgsSymbolLayer` (renamed from `QgsSymbolLayerV2`) says `usedAttributes()` now requires a `QgsRenderContext` argument. 
I've been poking at this for a long time and I feel I am close, but I just am not familiar enough with python to get over this hurdle.

[QGIS API](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/other/QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.html#qgis.core.QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 3.0 you'd need to make a copy of the existing symbol, edit it, and then save it back to the renderer:

```
renderer = layer.renderer()
# get the current symbol
range = renderer.ranges()[1]
current_symbol = range.symbol()
# make a new copy of it
new_symbol = current_symbol.clone()
# edit the symbol properties
new_symbol.setSize(1.5)
# save it back to the graduated class
renderer.updateRangeSymbol(1, new_symbol)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Only one issue is as soon as I issue the clone command it crashes QGIS! Filed a crash report.

Comment: I was told I need to store a reference to the range object or the symbol will be garbage collected before you can call clone() on it: `layer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
renderer = layer.renderer()
renderer_range = renderer.ranges()[1]
current_symbol = renderer_range.symbol()
new_symbol = current_symbol.clone()
new_symbol.setSize(1.5)
renderer.updateRangeSymbol(1, new_symbol)`

Comment: I got it to refresh after adding these two lines `qgis.utils.iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
layer.triggerRepaint()` which I found in the answer here [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284057/how-to-change-layer-symbology-in-qgis-3-with-qgsfeaturerendererv2)

Answer (score 1):

For context, you need to add `QgsRenderContext()` to the render symbol list call.  So, your code from Qgis 2.18 would become:

`layer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
symbols = layer.renderer().symbols(QgsRenderContext())
symbols[0].setSize(1.5)
symbols[1].setSize(1.75)
symbols[2].setSize(2)
symbols[3].setSize(2.25)
symbols[4].setSize(2.5)
symbols[5].setSize(2.75)`